# How can I delete records that have the same values in two non-primary key columns while factoring in a third?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a link to a sqlfiddle with sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d8d552/3

I'm trying to delete 1 row from rows that have the same values in both name and color. If they have they same score, then it doesn't matter which one is deleted. If those rows have a different score, then I want to delete the row with the lower score.

I'm getting it down to the correct rows (but with an extra row with the same score that I would want to keep one of) using an inner join, but I'm having difficulty differentiating between scores.

Another route I've tried is with the 2nd query that gets me the exact rows I want to delete, but then I can't seem to get the ItemID as it's not part of the aggregate function or GROUP BY. Using the function ROW_NUMBER() helps get the correct rows, but makes it difficult to get the IDs to delete.

**I'm looking to delete ItemIds 1 and 9 and then 1 of (2,4) and 1 of (6,8)**

| ItemID | name | color | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | asdf | green | 5 |
| 2 | asdf | blue | 4 |
| 3 | asdf | green | 6 |
| 4 | asdf | blue | 4 |
| 5 | asdf | yellow | 0 |
| 6 | qwer | green | 3 |
| 7 | qwer | blue | 3 |
| 8 | qwer | green | 3 |
| 9 | qwer | blue | 2 |
| 10 | qwer | yellow | 0 |

Here is some SQL that I've tried out which gets me close:

```
SELECT I.*
FROM Items I
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT name, color, MIN(score) AS ms
     FROM Items
     GROUP BY name, color
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) s ON I.name = s.name 
                            AND I.color = s.color 
                            AND I.score = ms
ORDER BY I.ItemID
GO

SELECT 
    name, color, MIN(score) AS minScore, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, color
                       ORDER BY MIN(score)) AS rn
FROM Items
GROUP BY name, color
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY name
```

---

### EDIT

I believe @Susang 's answer works better than mine. Here's a link to a fiddle with it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d8873/5

Comment: Your question is incomplete because we can't see your data directly posted here.  Please delete the links (you can keep the Fiddle link), and instead include all relevant information here.

Comment: Its awesome to include a dbfiddle, but your question needs to be stand alone and include everything required.

Comment: I've just updated it. I included some code that I've tried as well. For future reference are images generally looked down on? Even in addition to code and data or are they not that helpful?

Comment: @cyriacalex This is a nice article explaining about [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). I hope this helps

Comment: Thank @Luuk, that was helpful to read through and I appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTE as below:

```
CREATE TABLE #test(ItemID INT,  name varchar(50),   color varchar(50),  score INT)
INSERT INTO #test(ItemID, name, color, score) VALUES
(1,     'asdf',     'green',    5),
(2,     'asdf',     'blue',     4),
(3,     'asdf',     'green',    6),
(4,     'asdf',     'blue',     4),
(5,     'asdf',     'yellow',   0),
(6,     'qwer',     'green',    3),
(7,     'qwer',     'blue',     3),
(8,     'qwer',     'green',    3),
(9,     'qwer',     'blue',     2),
(10,    'qwer',     'yellow',   0)

;WITH recDelete AS (
    SELECT 
        rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, color ORDER BY score DESC),
        ItemID
    FROM #test
)
DELETE FROM recDelete WHERE rnk > 1
```

Comment: I think I like your solution better than the one I found and put in my edit. That way requires two aggregate functions while this only takes one. Nice job.

Comment: Is the inner join necessary? Could you just delete from the CTE and use the same WHERE clause? Or is that potentially more dangerous?

Comment: @cyriacalex window functions are not allowed in the WHERE clause but yes `INNER JOIN` is not necessary. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an updatable CTE!  This is simple:

```
WITH todelete AS (
       SELECT i.*
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, color ORDER BY score DESC) as seqnum
       FROM items i
      )
DELETE todelete
    WHERE seqnum > 1;
```

No `JOIN` is needed.